# Where are the Motion Blur controls in 2.76b as shown in the Manual?

Tags: rendering, blur

Under the Render tab (Cycles Render), the motion blur options are very simple compared to what I see in the Manual:  https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/motion_blur.html#options

Where can I find these extra motion blur controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like they already updated the documentation for the the upcoming 2.77 release. The [test builds](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.77/) do have these extended controls.